# What is the difference in httpclient4 and Java type in JMeter test script recorder?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new with the JMeter tool. I am using JMeter Test Script Recorder to capture the traffic. In that I have found there is different type are available like "httpclient4", "Java" & "Blank". So what is the exact difference of these types. Does it make any difference in my script if I select any different type.

I have googled it also but didn't get exact particular answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per [HTTP Request sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

> HTTP Request
>
> this has an implementation drop-down box, which selects the HTTP protocol implementation 
>   to be used:
>
> **Java**
>
> uses the HTTP implementation provided by the JVM. This has some limitations in comparison with the HttpClient implementations - see below.
>
> **HTTPClient4**
>
> uses Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 4.x.
>
> **Blank Value**
>
> does not set implementation on HTTP Samplers, so relies on HTTP Request Defaults if
>
> present or on jmeter.httpsampler property defined in jmeter.properties
>
> The Java HTTP implementation has some limitations:
>
> - There is no control over how connections are re-used. When a connection is released by
> - JMeter, it may or may not be re-used by the same thread.
> - The API is best suited to single-threaded usage - various settings are defined via 
>     system properties, and therefore apply to all connections.
> - There is a bug in the handling of HTTPS via a Proxy (the CONNECT is not handled correctly). See Java bugs 6226610 and 6208335.
> - It does not support virtual hosts.
> - It supports only the following methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE and TRACE
> - It does not support client based certificate testing with Keystore Config.

In addition you will not be able to use [Kerberos](https://www.varonis.com/blog/kerberos-authentication-explained/) or [emulate slow connections](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)

---

Assuming all above either set it to be `HttpClient4` or leave blank - by default it should be `HttpClient4` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases,
`httpclient4` will throw this exception

```
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
```

which `java` won't.